# Finding a path in residual network

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, ford-fulkerson

First, implement the flow network G = (V, E). Let G' = (V, E') be the residual network, where  E' = {(u, v) : (u, v) is in E or (v,u) is in E}.

The issue I am having is understanding the following text from CLRS:

> The time to find a path in a residual network is therefore O(V + E') = O(E) if we use either depth-first search or breadth-first search.

According to this [source](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-if-there-is-a-path-between-two-vertices-in-a-given-graph), BFS/DFS takes O(V + E), so why is O(V + E') = O(E)?

Comment: You are only going to search the subgraph that is connected to the source.  For a connected graph V <= E+1

Comment: @MattTimmermans So since the residue graph is a connected graph, the number of edges is greater than or equal the number of vertices. Hence, the time complexity can be said to be O(E) since the size of the edges is known. If I am understanding this correctly, is this the reason why BFS/DFS takes O(V + E) because the time complexity is dependent on the number of vertices and edges which is not known as it is dependent on the graph provided (connected or not)?

Comment: It's generally O(V+E) for BFS/DFS, because you can have V > O(E), if many vertices have no edges at all.  Of course that cannot happen in a connected graph.